# Flask - How to create multiple instances of a model on a single form submit?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask

I am creating a poll application in Flask.
I have 2 models: Question and Choice (similar to Django documentation)
Here are my models:

```
class Question(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  content = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
  date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

  def __repr__(self):
    return f'<Question {self.id}>'

class Choice(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  content = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)

  def __repr__(self):
    return f'<Choice {self.id}>'
```

Here is my HTML form:

```
  <form action="/create/" method="POST">
    <p>Question: <input type="text" name="question"></p>
    <p>Choice 1: <input type="text" name="choice-0"></p>
    <p>Choice 2: <input type="text" name="choice-1"></p>
    <p>Choice 3: <input type="text" name="choice-2"></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Create">
  </form>
```

Here is the code I wrote to implement creation of new instances upon form submission:

```
@app.route('/create/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def create():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    question_content = request.form['question']
    new_question = Question(content = question_content)

    for choice in range(3):
      new_choices = []
      new_choices.append(Choice(content = request.form[f'choice-{choice}']))
    
    try:
      db.session.add(new_question)
      for choice in new_choices:
        db.session.add(choice)
      db.session.commit()
      return redirect('/')
    except:
      return 'There was an error in creating your poll'

  else:
    return render_template('create.html')
```

My problem is that after I test it out, I check the items in my Choices table to see that only the first one was created.

Comment: ` new_choices = []` should be outside the for loop.

Comment: Well do I feel like a dummy...